# Unexpected leak caused by @throw in block

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, objective-c-blocks

I have the following object:

```
typedef void(^Block1)();
typedef void(^Block2)(Block1 block1);

@interface Test : NSObject
@end
@implementation Test
-(void)test:(Block2)block2 {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    Block1 block1 = ^{
      // intentionally hold a ref of current object
      [self doNothing];
    };

    @try {
      block2(block1);
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
      // do nothing
    }
  });
}
-(void)doNothing { }
-(void)dealloc{
  NSLog(@"deallocated: %@", self);
}
@end
```

And I use it like the following:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
      Test *t = [[Test alloc] init];
      [t test:^(Block1 block1) {
        // this @throw statement causes leak? 
        @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"ERROR" reason:nil userInfo:nil];
      }];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I @throw exception from `Block2`(As I did above), `-dealloc` method will never be called, If I do anything other than @throwing exceptions, everything works as expected.

Did I do anything wrong in the code or is this a bug?

Comment: Can't remember the source but ARC by default leaks with exception. You need to enable some flag to fix it. However because exception on ObjC normally means your app is about to crash, so it doesn't matter most of the time.

Comment: just find out my comments two years ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27140891/why-does-try-catch-in-objective-c-cause-memory-leak#comment42779256_27140891

Comment: Don't throw exceptions in Objective-C except to deal with clear programming issues. Use "normal" error handling in Objective-C (such as a `nil` or `BOOL` return value and an `NSError` out-parameter just like in all of Apple's APIs.

Comment: @rmaddy _most_ of Apple's APIs

Comment: @BryanChen Do you have an example of Apple using a catchable exception that is actually used for proper error handling as opposed to exceptions being thrown due to programming errors?

Comment: @rmaddy `[NSFileHandle writeData:]` is one very frustrating example, along with most of `NSFileHandle`. (I am in no way disagreeing with your assertion about the correct use and meaning of exceptions.)

Comment: @BryanChen, thanks for having found the duplicate, saved my day.